# To create dictionaries with keys and values alone as a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
name_list = ["David Joyner", "David Zuber", "Brenton Joyner",
             "Brenton Zuber", "Nicol Barthel", "Shelba Barthel",
             "Shelba Crowley", "Shelba Fernald", "Shelba Odle",
             "Shelba Fry", "Maren Fry"]
```

This is the list and the answer should be:

```
{'Shelba': ['Shelba Barthel', 'Shelba Crowley', 'Shelba Fernald', 'Shelba Odle', 'Shelba Fry'],'David': ['David Joyner', 'David Zuber'], 'Brenton': ['Brenton Joyner', 'Brenton Zuber'],'Maren': ['Maren Fry'], 'Nicol': ['Nicol Barthel']}
```

I'm new to python and learning the basics of dictionaries. It would be helpful if a code is provided for the problem.

Comment: @benvc I tried to separate the first name and save it as a separate list. Then I tried to compare the first name from the new list to the original name list. I'm having trouble in adding the value as a list instead of a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

This code may be helpful.

```
name_list = ["David Joyner", "David Zuber", "Brenton Joyner",
             "Brenton Zuber", "Nicol Barthel", "Shelba Barthel",
             "Shelba Crowley", "Shelba Fernald", "Shelba Odle",
             "Shelba Fry", "Maren Fry"]
result = {}
for name in name_list:
    first_name = name.split(' ')[0]
    if first_name in result:
        result[first_name].append(name)
    else:
        result.update({first_name:[name]})
print(result)
```

Comment: I haven't come across the update() method. So using that method, we can directly add values to the dictionary?

Comment: @Rajesh Anand10 Right